# find the ratio of amount of rice placed on a chessboard between first and second half of chessboard?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-series

[image]

I think the sequence for this is:

1, 2, 4, ...

I'm not sure what it means by first half of chessboard vs next half of chessboard. I'm assuming it is some kind of ratio?

Comment: Is the second half the top half? Or the right half?

Comment: yeah i'm confused about that as well. i think it means top vs bottom. but im not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: In chess, the "first half" and "second half" refer to the top and bottom half respectively. So all you need to do is find $\sum_{I = 0}^{31} 2^I$ and $\sum_{I = 32}^{63} 2^I$ for the bottom and top half respectively.

Comment: so what is the relevance of the 1,2,4,...

Comment: @user130306 I'm so sorry!I thought there is one grain in the first square, two in the second, three in the third, ... . I fixed it.

Comment: ah that makes sense, thank you!